# Facebook product XML feed error: There is no ProductItem for the id field with the specified id

Tags: xml, facebook, import, rss

I trying to validate XML feed by facebook validator: https://business.facebook.com/ads/product_feed/debug

I was trying to validate several XML feeds from googling. All of them give one mistake: "There is no ProductItem for the id field with the specified id".

There is no some example of XML product feed in the facebook. This is XML product feed from google documentation. It returns same eroor.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog/reference/ - I found facebook examples later. There is no mistakes with ids from this document. Why we have no problem with id 'DB_1', 'DB_2' from facebook example and we have mistake with another id 'DC_2'?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Example - Online Store</title>
        <link>http://www.example.com</link>
        <description>This is a sample feed containing the required and recommended attributes for a variety of different products</description>
        
        <!-- First example shows what attributes are required and recommended for items that are not in the apparel category -->
        <item>
            <!-- The following attributes are always required -->
            <g:id>TV_123456</g:id>
            <g:title>LG 22LB4510 - 22" LED TV - 1080p (FullHD)</g:title>
            <g:description>Attractively styled and boasting stunning picture quality, the LG 22LB4510 - 22&quot; LED TV - 1080p (FullHD) is an excellent television/monitor. The LG 22LB4510 - 22&quot; LED TV - 1080p (FullHD) sports a widescreen 1080p panel, perfect for watching movies in their original format, whilst also providing plenty of working space for your other applications.</g:description>
            <g:link>http://www.example.com/electronics/tv/22LB4510.html</g:link>
            <g:image_link>http://images.example.com/TV_123456.png</g:image_link>
            <g:condition>used</g:condition>
            <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
            <g:price>159.00 USD</g:price>
            <g:shipping>
                <g:country>US</g:country>
                <g:service>Standard</g:service>
                <g:price>14.95 USD</g:price>
            </g:shipping>
            
            <!-- 2 of the following 3 attributes are required fot this item according to the Unique Product Identifier Rules -->
            <g:gtin>71919219405200</g:gtin>
            <g:brand>LG</g:brand>
            <g:mpn>22LB4510/US</g:mpn>
            
            <!-- The following attributes are not required for this item, but supplying them is recommended -->
            <g:google_product_category>Electronics > Video > Televisions > Flat Panel Televisions</g:google_product_category>
            <g:product_type>Consumer Electronics &gt; TVs &gt; Flat Panel TVs</g:product_type>
        </item>
        
        <!-- Second example demonstrates the use of CDATA sections instead of entities to deal with special characters. Note that CDATA sections can be used for any attribute -->
        <item>
            <!-- The following attributes are always required -->
            <g:id>DVD-0564738</g:id>
            <g:title><![CDATA[Merlin: Series 3 - Volume 2 - 3 DVD Box set]]></g:title>
            <g:description><![CDATA[Episodes 7-13 from the third series of the BBC fantasy drama set in the mythical city of Camelot, telling the tale of the relationship between the young King Arthur (Bradley James) & Merlin (Colin Morgan), the wise sorcerer who guides him to power and beyond. Episodes are: 'The Castle of Fyrien', 'The Eye of the Phoenix', 'Love in the Time of Dragons', 'Queen of Hearts', 'The Sorcerer's Shadow', 'The Coming of Arthur: Part 1' & 'The Coming of Arthur: Part 2']]></g:description>
            <g:link><![CDATA[http://www.example.com/media/dvd/?sku=384616&src=gshopping&lang=en]]></g:link>
            <g:image_link><![CDATA[http://images.example.com/DVD-0564738?size=large&format=PNG]]></g:image_link>
            <g:condition>new</g:condition>
            <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
            <g:price>11.99 USD</g:price>
            <g:shipping>
                <g:country>US</g:country>
                <g:service>Express Mail</g:service>
                <g:price>3.80 USD</g:price>
            </g:shipping>
            
            <!-- 2 out of the 3 unique product identifer attributes are required for this item -->
            <g:gtin>88392916560500</g:gtin>
            <g:brand>BBC</g:brand>
            
            <!-- The following attribute is required because this item is in the 'Media' category -->
            <g:google_product_category><![CDATA[Media > DVDs & Videos]]></g:google_product_category>
            
            <!-- The following attributes are not required for this item, but supplying them is recommended if applicable -->
            <g:product_type><![CDATA[DVDs & Movies > TV Series > Fantasy Drama]]></g:product_type>
        </item>
        
        <!-- Third example shows how to include multiple images and shipping types-->
        <item>
            <!-- The following attributes are always required -->
            <g:id>PFM654321</g:id>
            <g:title>Dior Capture XP Ultimate Wrinkle Correction Creme 1.7 oz</g:title>
            <g:description>Dior Capture XP Ultimate Wrinkle Correction Creme 1.7 oz reinvents anti-wrinkle care by protecting and relaunching skin cell activity to encourage faster, healthier regeneration.</g:description>
            <g:link>http://www.example.com/perfumes/product?Dior%20Capture%20R6080%20XP</g:link>
            <g:image_link>http://images.example.com/PFM654321_1.jpg</g:image_link>
            <g:condition>new</g:condition>
            <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
            <g:price>99 USD</g:price>
            <g:shipping>
                <g:country>US</g:country>
                <g:service>Standard Rate</g:service>
                <g:price>4.95 USD</g:price>
            </g:shipping>
            <g:shipping>
                <g:country>US</g:country>
                <g:service>Next Day</g:service>
                <g:price>8.50 USD</g:price>
            </g:shipping>
            
            <!-- 2 out of the 3 unique product identifer attributes are required for this item  -->
            <g:gtin>3348901056069</g:gtin>
            <g:brand>Dior</g:brand>
            
            <!-- The following attributes are not required for this item, but supplying them is recommended if applicable -->
            <g:product_type>Health &amp; Beauty &gt; Personal Care &gt; Cosmetics &gt; Skin Care &gt; Lotion</g:product_type>
            <g:google_product_category>Health &amp; Beauty &gt; Personal Care &gt; Cosmetics &gt; Skin Care &gt; Anti-Aging Skin Care Kits</g:google_product_category>
            <g:additional_image_link>http://images.example.com/PFM654321_2.jpg</g:additional_image_link>
            <g:additional_image_link>http://images.example.com/PFM654321_3.jpg</g:additional_image_link>
        </item>
        
        <!-- Fourth example shows what attributes are required and recommended for items that are in the apparel category -->
        <item>
            <!-- The following attributes are always required -->
            <g:id>CLO-29473856-1</g:id>
            <g:title>Roma Cotton Rich Bootcut Jeans - Size 8 Standard</g:title>
            <g:description>A smart pair of bootcut jeans in stretch cotton.</g:description>
            <g:link>http://www.example.com/clothing/women/Roma-Cotton-Bootcut-Jeans/?extid=CLO-29473856</g:link>
            <g:image_link>http://images.example.com/CLO-29473856-front.jpg</g:image_link>
            <g:condition>new</g:condition>
            <g:availability>out of stock</g:availability>   
            <g:price>29.50 USD</g:price>
                    
            <!-- The following attributes are required because this item is apparel -->
            <g:google_product_category>Apparel &amp; Accessories &gt; Clothing &gt; Pants &gt; Jeans</g:google_product_category>
            <g:brand>M&amp;S</g:brand>
            <g:gender>Female</g:gender>
            <g:age_group>Adult</g:age_group>
            <g:color>Navy</g:color>
            <g:size>8 Standard</g:size>
            
            <!-- The following attribute is required because this item has variants -->
            <g:item_group_id>CLO-29473856</g:item_group_id>
            
            <!-- The following attributes are not required for this item, but supplying them is recommended if applicable -->
            <g:mpn>B003J5F5EY</g:mpn>
            <g:product_type>Women's Clothing &gt; Jeans &gt; Bootcut Jeans</g:product_type>
            <g:additional_image_link>http://images.example.com/CLO-29473856-side.jpg</g:additional_image_link>
            <g:additional_image_link>http://images.example.com/CLO-29473856-back.jpg</g:additional_image_link>
        </item>
        
        <!-- This is a variant of the last item (same 'item group id'). In this case the variant is only by size, but the item could be repeated in the same way for other variants -->
        <item>
            <!-- The following attributes are always required -->
            <g:id>CLO-29473856-2</g:id>
            <g:title>Roma Cotton Rich Bootcut Jeans - Size 8 Tall</g:title>
            <g:description>A smart pair of bootcut jeans in stretch cotton.</g:description>
            <g:link>http://www.example.com/clothing/women/Roma-Cotton-Bootcut-Jeans/?extid=CLO-29473856</g:link>
            <g:image_link>http://images.example.com/CLO-29473856-front.jpg</g:image_link>
            <g:condition>new</g:condition>
            <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
            <g:price>29.50 USD</g:price>
                        
            <!-- The following attributes are required because this item is apparel -->
            <g:google_product_category>Apparel &amp; Accessories &gt; Clothing &gt; Pants &gt; Jeans</g:google_product_category>
            <g:brand>M&amp;S</g:brand>
            <g:gender>Female</g:gender>
            <g:age_group>Adult</g:age_group>
            <g:color>Navy</g:color>
            <g:size>8 Tall</g:size>
            
            <!-- The following attribute is required because this item has variants -->
            <g:item_group_id>CLO-29473856</g:item_group_id>
            
            <!-- The following attributes are not required for this item, but supplying them is recommended if applicable -->
            <g:mpn>B003J5F5EY</g:mpn>
            <g:product_type>Women's Clothing &gt; Jeans &gt; Bootcut Jeans</g:product_type>
            <g:additional_image_link>http://images.example.com/CLO-29473856-side.jpg</g:additional_image_link>
            <g:additional_image_link>http://images.example.com/CLO-29473856-back.jpg</g:additional_image_link>
        </item>
        
        <!-- Fifth example demonstrates the use of the sale price attributes  -->
        <item>
            <!-- The following attributes are always required -->
            <g:id>CLO-1029384</g:id>
            <g:title>Tenn Cool Flow Ladies Long Sleeved Cycle Jersey</g:title>
            <g:description>A ladies' cycling jersey designed for the serious cyclist, tailored to fit a feminine frame. This sporty, vibrant red, black and white jersey is constructed of a special polyester weave that is extremely effective at drawing moisture away from your body, helping to keep you dry.  With an elasticised, gripping waist, it will stay in place for the duration of your cycle, and won't creep up like many other products. It has two elasticised rear pockets and the sleeves are elasticated to prevent creep-up.</g:description>
            <g:link>http://www.example.com/clothing/sports/product?id=CLO1029384&amp;src=gshopping&amp;popup=false</g:link>
            <g:image_link>http://images.example.com/CLO-1029384.jpg</g:image_link>
            <g:condition>new</g:condition>
            <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
            <g:price>33.99 USD</g:price>
            <g:shipping>
                <g:country>US</g:country>
                <g:service>Standard Free Shipping</g:service>
                <g:price>0 USD</g:price>
            </g:shipping>
            
            <!-- The following attributes are required because this item is apparel -->
            <g:brand>Tenn Cool</g:brand>
            <g:google_product_category>Apparel &amp; Accessories &gt; Clothing &gt; Activewear &gt; Bicycle Activewear &gt; Bicycle Jerseys</g:google_product_category>
            <g:gender>Female</g:gender>
            <g:age_group>Adult</g:age_group>
            <g:color>Black/Red/White</g:color> <!-- Indicates all the colours found on the garment in order of dominance -->
            <g:size>M</g:size>
            
            <!-- The following demonstrate the use of the 'sale price' and 'sale price effective date' and attributes -->
            <g:sale_price>25.49 USD</g:sale_price>
            <g:sale_price_effective_date>2011-09-01T16:00-08:00/2011-09-03T16:00-08:00</g:sale_price_effective_date>
            
            <!-- The following attributes are not required for this item, but supplying them is recommended if applicable -->
            <g:gtin>5060155240282</g:gtin>          
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Have someone some ideas about this?

Comment: Having the same trouble with CSV feeds, despite following the published specs ( https://www.facebook.com/business/help/120325381656392?id=725943027795860 ). Even tried Facebooks own CSV example.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog/reference/ - I found an examples of feeds on the facebook. I try XML examples in the facebook validator. Id from examples was handling without mistakes. Maybe some limitations for the id field? But I see just "max-lenght=100" limitation: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/120325381656392 thats all. (( Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's some bug in the facebook's feed validator.
I found facebook examples of feeds: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog/reference/

If I use id from facebook's example it works great. I taken this id and checked of my feed elem. When I fixed all mistakes from validator. My id handling great in the upload despite validator errors.